# Search a semicolon delimited list for specific values in SQL

Tags: sql, netezza

I'm using Netezza. I have a field that stores data like below, using fruit as an example:

```
Fruits
----------------
APPLE; PEAR; ORANGE
PEAR
BANANA; LEMON; APPLE
APPLE; ORANGE
```

I want to return rows containing only a combination of "Apple," "Pear," or "Orange." So from the above data set, the rows I would want to have returned are:

```
Fruits
-----------------
APPLE; PEAR; ORANGE
PEAR
APPLE; ORANGE
```

The third record from the original table is not returned because even though it has the word "Apple," it also contains the words "Banana" and "Lemon," whereas I ONLY want rows that contain one or more of "Apple," "Pear," or "Orange." All of the values are semicolon delimited. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you have a specific set of entries so that it's not possible to get something like `HFfsdsSHOrange` then you can always use `LIKE` statements. E.g. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE Fruits LIKE "%APPLE%" OR Fruits LIKE "%PEAR%" OR FRUITS LIKE "%ORANGE%";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with substitution.  Remove the strings you don't like and be sure nothing is left:

```
select f.*
from fruits f
where replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(col, 'APPLE', ''), 'PEAR', ''), 'ORANGE', ''), ';', ''), ' ', '') = '';
```

Comment: The end result is kinda long (I have 10 strings in total), but it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Netezza supports regular expressions, you can remove all those keywords and check if the result is empty:

```
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '( ){0,1}(APPLE|PEAR|ORANGE);{0,1}', '', 1, 0, 'i') = ''
```

This removes the optional leading blank & trailing semicolon, too.

Edit:

Another, simplified version:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '(APPLE|PEAR|ORANGE|;|( ))', '', 1, 0, 'i')
```

Comment: I just tried this and got the following error: Unable to identify a function that satisfies the given argument types. You may need to add explicit typecasts.

Comment: @user3642531: Different DBMSes have some slight syntax variations for regular expressions. Seems you need to add the replacement string, I'll fix my answer....

Comment: This code only returns rows containing just the first value in the list (so in the example case, just APPLE). Perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @user3642531: I don't know about the specific regex implementation in Netezza, this is a generic regex which works on my Teradata (should work on Oracle, too). I added another simplified version, don't know if it works on Netezza...

Comment: I wish I was proficient enough in regex to be sure what the issue is...but thanks for the advice!